# Evaluation of Standard Normal Integral

Tags: integration, probability-theory, numerical-methods

I have always wondered how we calculate the percentiles of the Standard Normal Distribution given that the CDF cannot be obtained in closed form:

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} $$

Do we approximate the function somehow? I have seen some texts that employ the Taylor Series of $e^x$, i.e. $e^x = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $ but this is not very practical. Is there another way to approximate the integral at a satisfactory level? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @LordSoth What you are saying is that we normally calculate the Standard Normal percentiles by approximating the Error Function and then using the relation between those two?

Comment: Yes, that may be one way to do it as $\mathrm{erf}(\cdot)$ is a quite well-studied function.

Comment: Right. What about numerical integration techniques though? Are any applicable for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at some of the approximations of the error function in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm).  Some of these may be derived by guessing the approximate form and fitting coefficients of the form to various numerically derived data points.  This is evident in formulae 7.1.25-7.1.28.  Unfortunately, much of applied mathematics can be a little on the ugly side like this; the results, however, are incredibly practical.

Comment: Thank you. I am feeling a bit overwhelmed though. Other than the Error Function do you think that any of Newton's numerical integration formulas are applicable?

Comment: @Ioannis: well, sure, but you need to be careful not to go too high in order: you end up assuming more crazy behavior than is warranted with a gaussian.  The thing is, the error function is so well-known and cheap to compute, there are a hundred ways to do it.  If you do not have access to a black box code, then the polynomials I referred to work beautifully.  Otherwise, just use a black box error function.  Unless you are learning about the structure of the function, there is really no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks again. I still have a lot to learn.